# Writing each integer as a rational number

Tags: real-analysis, integers, rational-numbers

Suppose the rational number is defined as $\mathbb{Q}:=X / \sim$ where $X:=\mathbb{Z} \times(\mathbb{Z} \backslash\{0\})$ and $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on X and assume all properties of addition and multiplication of the integers is defined, how do I show that for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, there is a rational number $[(a, b)] \in \mathbb{Q}$ that corresponds to $n$ rigorously? I know that the answer is $[(n, 1)]$ but what additional things I have to show in order to answer the question? I know I might have to show that this $[(n, 1)]$ is unique but I cannot think of anything else. Can someone hint at it to me?

Comment: @lulu Hi, I have fixed it so it is defined as set of all equivalence classes in X with respect to the relation ∼

Comment: I think you are already aware of the ring isomorphism between  $\mathbb{Z} $ and the set of equivalence classes of the form $[(n, 1)]$. That's the only thing needed.

Comment: A rational number $q \in \mathbb Q$ has a natural correspondence to an equivalence class, i.e. the subset of $\mathbb{Z} \times(\mathbb{Z} \backslash\{0\})$ namely to $\{(a,b):qb=a\}$, with each such subset being disinct for each $q$.  You can choose a representative element of such a subset by choosing the one for $b$ is positive and minimal.  If $b$ is positive then it cannot be smaller than $1$. The rationals with correspond to integers where the representative element has $b=1$, i.e. where the subset of  $\mathbb{Z} \times(\mathbb{Z} \backslash\{0\})$ has an element of the form $(n,1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to show is that the mapping $\ \varphi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow X/\sim\ $ defined by
$$
\varphi(n)=[(n,1)]=\left\{(mn,m)\,|\,m\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}\right\}
$$
is an isomorphism when the addition and multiplication of $\ X/\sim\ $ are defined in the obvious way.

**Addendum:**
It is also the case that $\ \varphi\ $ is the *only* isomorphism between $\ \mathbb{Z}\ $ and any subset of $\ X/\sim\ $.  It has occurred to me that if this question were asked as part of a test or an exercise in a course, the person asking the question *might* be expecting you to prove this uniqueness as well.